# NLopt error in Julia and Ipopt alternative

Tags: optimization, constraints, julia

I have the following simple problem that I want to solve with NLopt:

```
using JuMP
using NLopt

"""
min_x = x1 * x4* (x1 + x2 + x3) + x3

s.t.
x1 * x2 * x3 * x4 >= 25
x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 40
1 <= x1,x2,x3,x4 <= 5

starting values: vec(x) = (x1 = 1, x2 = 5, x3 = 5, x4 = 1)
"""


tic()

m = Model(solver=NLoptSolver(algorithm=:LD_MMA))


@defVar(m, 1 <= x1 <= 5)
@defVar(m, 1 <= x2 <= 5)
@defVar(m, 1 <= x3 <= 5)
@defVar(m, 1 <= x4 <= 5)

@setNLObjective(m, Min,  x1 * x4 * (x1 + x2 + x3) + x3)
@addNLConstraint(m, x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 == 40)
@addNLConstraint(m, x1 * x2 * x3 * x4 >= 25)

setValue(x1, 1)
setValue(x2, 5)
setValue(x3, 5)
setValue(x4, 1)

status = solve(m)

println("got ", getObjectiveValue(m), " at ", [getValue(x1),getValue(x2), getValue(x3), getValue(x4)])

toc()
```

However I get an argument error. Is there any way to make this work with NLopt and if not how this code can change so as to use it with the other free optimizers that can be installed in Julia (maybe Ipopt but not Gurobi)?

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: ERROR: ArgumentError("invalid NLopt arguments") in chk at (path of NLopt) in push at array.jl:458 in equality constraint! at (NLopt path) while loading (my_file)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was unable to solve the problem using NLopt, but instead I managed to solve it with Ipopt.

The solution is simple for using Ipopt. Firstly you have to download Ipopt (I used the Windows version for now and I will also try in Linux) from this [site](http://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Ipopt/) and put it in the path (if you put it in the path and go to the command line and type `ipopt` it must show no error-it will actually show `ipopt` options). Just go at the very end to find the newest version.

Then I sliglty modified the code that I provided before to account for Ipopt in this way:

```
using JuMP

using Ipopt


"""
The problem that I want to solve has 4 variables and 6 constraints.
It is the following:


min_x = x1x4(x1+x2+x3) + x3


s.t.

x1*x2*x3*x4 >= 25
x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2 = 40
1 <= x1,x2,x3,x4 <= 5


starting values: x0 = (x1 = 1, x2 = 5, x3 = 5, x4 = 1)
"""


tic()


m = Model(solver=IpoptSolver())


@defVar(m, 1 <= x1 <= 5)
@defVar(m, 1 <= x2 <= 5)
@defVar(m, 1 <= x3 <= 5)
@defVar(m, 1 <= x4 <= 5)


@setNLObjective(m, Min,  x1 * x4 * (x1 + x2 + x3) + x3)
@addNLConstraint(m, x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 == 40)
@addNLConstraint(m, x1 * x2 * x3 * x4 >= 25)


setValue(x1, 1)
setValue(x2, 5)
setValue(x3, 5)
setValue(x4, 1)

status = solve(m)

println("got ", getObjectiveValue(m), " at ", [getValue(x1),getValue(x2), 
getValue(x3), getValue(x4)])

toc()
```

More information about the right name of the solvers etc. can be found here: https://jump.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html#getting-solvers

Comment: `Pkg.add("Ipopt")` will actually install Ipopt automatically and ready for use with Julia.

Comment: To follow up on Iain's comment, the Ipopt.jl interface does not use the ipopt command-line executable. There's no need to set it up manually.